# Windows 10 not opening jupyter notebook in Command Prompt

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, windows-10, jupyter

I tried to open the jupyter notebook using Command Prompt on Windows 10. Instead of it opening in the browser as it should, nothing happens.

I have downloaded jupyter using

```
pip install jupyter
pip install jupyter notebook
```

All this worked fine but when I type this in Command Prompt only a new line forms and nothing happens.

```
C:\Users\meena\OneDrive\Desktop\New folder>jupyter notebook

C:\Users\meena\OneDrive\Desktop\New folder>
```

I have tried to install jupyter many times but it doesn't work. 
I only have python and not anaconda. So if someone else has the same problem and has tried anaconda please tell me so I can download it.

Comment: Can you import jupyter in the python shell?

Comment: Check if the jupyter command is going to the correct location using `where jupyter`.  If it looks correct, check the version information using `jupyter --version`, please post this info.

Comment: ```C:\Users\meena>where jupyter
C:\Users\meena\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\jupyter.exe

C:\Users\meena>jupyter --version
jupyter core     : 4.5.0
jupyter-notebook : 5.7.8
qtconsole        : 4.5.5
ipython          : 7.8.0
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried typing `jupyter-notebook` and see if it works? I upgraded Anaconda recently, and typing `jupyter notebook` stopped working for some of my files, but I solved the problem by typing `jupyter-notebook`.

Comment: this is more of a comment since it does not explain how to solve..